# Number-Guessing-Game in bash

Tags: bash

I wrote a simple bash script for number(1-100) guessing game. There I added a parameter where "-a" argument runs a function to automatically guess the number. Mostly it ("-a") works okay meanwhile sometimes it gets stuck in an infinite loop. I tried debugging it. After many trial and error I am still stuck. Any suggestions?

You can find the entire script [here](https://github.com/tousifanaam/Number-Guessing-Game)

The following is what gets executed for the argument "-a"

```sh
# variables
a=$((1 + $RANDOM % 100))
guess=50; failure=0 
ll=1 # lower_limit 
ul=100 # upper_limit

# Start
if [ $guess -eq $a ];then
    attempts=$(($failure+1))
    echo -e "\n${guess} - Correct guess!. No. of attempts taken: $attempts"
    exit
elif [ $guess -gt $a ];then
    echo -e "\n${guess} - Too High!" # -
    pg2=$guess; failure=$(($failure+1))
    guess=$((${ul}/4))
elif [ $guess -lt $a ];then
    echo -e "\n${guess} - Too Low!" # +
    pg2=$guess; failure=$(($failure+1))
    guess=$(($guess+$((${guess}/2))))
fi
pg1=$guess # output variables: guess = 25 or 75, pg1 = 25 or 75, pg2 = 50

# Main 
check () {
if [ $guess -eq $a ];then
    attempts=$(($failure+1))
    echo -e "\n${guess} - Correct guess!. No. of attempts taken: $attempts"; n=1
    exit
elif [ $guess -gt $a ];then 
    echo -e "\n${guess} - Too High!" # -
    if [ $pg2 -gt $pg1 ];then # previous guess was an output of too high
        pg3=$pg2; pg2=$pg1; failure=$(($failure+1)) 
        guess=$(($(($ll+$pg2))/2))
    elif [ $pg2 -lt $pg1 ];then # previous guess was an output of too low
        pg3=$pg2; pg2=$pg1; failure=$(($failure+1)) 
        guess=$(($(($pg3+$pg2))/2))
    fi
elif [ $guess -lt $a ];then
    echo -e "\n${guess} - Too Low!" # +
    if [ $pg2 -gt $pg1 ];then # previous guess was an output of too high
        pg3=$pg2; pg2=$pg1; failure=$(($failure+1)) 
        guess=$(($(($pg2+$pg3))/2))
    elif [ $pg2 -lt $pg1 ];then # previous guess was an output of too low
        pg3=$pg2; pg2=$pg1; failure=$(($failure+1)) 
        guess=$(($(($pg2+$ul))/2))
    fi  
fi 
pg1=$guess 
}

# Loop Main
n=0
while [ $n -eq 0 ];do
    check
done
```

In place of defining the random number variable `$a` when I use this piece:

```sh
blacklist () {
n=0
while [ $n -eq 0 ];do
    a=$((1 + $RANDOM % 100))
    if [ $a -eq 13 ] || [ $a -eq 43 ] || [ $a -eq 53 ] || [ $a -eq 63 ] || [ $a -eq 76 ] || [ $a -eq 51 ] || [ $a -eq 71 ] || [ $a -eq 44 ] || [ $a -eq 73 ] || [ $a -eq 46 ] || [ $a -eq 60 ] || [ $a -eq 48 ] || [ $a -eq 78 ] || [ $a -eq 52 ] || [ $a -eq 20 ] || [ $a -eq 47 ] || [ $a -eq 77 ] || [ $a -eq 49 ] || [ $a -eq 79 ] || [ $a -eq 35 ] || [ $a -eq 45 ] || [ $a -eq 55 ] || [ $a -eq 85 ] || [ $a -eq 61 ] || [ $a -eq 21 ] || [ $a -eq 54 ] || [ $a -eq 14 ] || [ $a -eq 42 ] || [ $a -eq 36 ] || [ $a -eq 100 ];then
        n=0
    else
        n=1
    fi
done
}
blacklist
```

Then things seems to run fine but as you can see I have to black list certain numbers. Which gives me a conclusion that there is a logical error which I am yet to find.

Comment: Insert the relevant program code in your question (no links).

Comment: Please paste your script at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: Even after you put some code in the question, it's not a [mcve].

Comment: `guess=$(($(($pg3+$pg2))/2))` no need for extra `$(())` and no need for `$`. Just `guess=$(( (pg3+pg2) / 2 ))` or even `(( guess = (pg3 + pg2) / 2 ))`

Comment: The infinite loop seems clear: you never change the `$n` value.

Comment: @glennjackman the loop end when the condition `$guess -eq $a` is fulfilled - third line of `check()` function. Thanks for taking time and review the code. To my understanding there is a logical error - which I'm missing out.

Comment: @Cyrus Thank you for suggesting this awesome link: http://www.shellcheck.net/. It did help me to learn cleaner coding in bash.

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: I missed that. I think that's a comment about the readability of your code. One statement per line is the usual advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Advice:

- don't duplicate your logic. Instead of setting extra variables, the check function can modify the current lower and upper bounds, as appropriate.
- write tidy code: readable code is maintainable code.